# Is it OK to uninstall the Xamarin Installer software on Mac

Tags: xamarin, macos-sierra

When we install Xamarin Studio, the installer file obviously gets installed too and it comes in around more than 3GB in size.

SO would it be OK to uninstall this or would this be essential for the future, e.g. maybe it is needed for future software updates?

Comment: Where is this installer file located?

Comment: ~/Library/Caches/XamarinInstaller.
Also within Applications folder.

Comment: I asked because I haven't seen a file like that on my hard drive. Decided to check anyway and there's no installation file in sight. My updates have worked like charm so that leads me to think that you'll be safe to delete that stuff altogether.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll check it out

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All the files under ~/Library/Caches/XamarinInstaller can be deleted and won't affect your development environment. These are kept in case you want to re-install the various components.

> Update: This now also applies to all files under ~/Library/Caches/VisualStudio/8.0/TempDownload